# Magic Number output

Tags: c++, loops, output

Alright so I have created this code. However, when i run it, it stops when it displays 104 for the counter??? I am so frustrated because I don't know how this could happen. The purpose of the code is to do the typical magic number output where the rows all add up to the same thing, the columns all add up to the same thing, and the diaganols all add up to the same thing. I believe the functions to do these calculations are correct, but the counter keeps stopping short of the 10000 attempts I am trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;




void getrandom();
void insertnumber(int n);
bool magic();
void create();
const int rows = 3;
const int cols = 3;
int arr[rows][cols] = { {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} , {0,0,0} };


int main() {
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        counter++;
        cout << counter << endl;
        getrandom();

        if (counter == 100000)
            break;


    } while (!magic());

    create();
    cout << "It took " << counter << " tries." << endl;

    return 0;
}





void getrandom() {
    int n = 0;
    const int size = 9;
    int oldnum[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        oldnum[i] = 0;
    }
    srand(time(NULL)); // had to import the new libraries to use this
    bool used = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        do
        {
            used = true;

            n = rand() % 9 + 1;
            if (oldnum[n - 1] == 0)
            {
                oldnum[n - 1] = n;
                used = false;

            }

        } while (used);
        insertnumber(n);
    }
}


void insertnumber(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                arr[i][j] = n;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool magic() {
    int rowsum = arr[0][0] + arr[0][1] + arr[0][2];

    for (int i = 1; i < cols; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i][0] + arr[i][1] + arr[i][2] != rowsum)
            return false;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        if (arr[0][j] + arr[1][j] + arr[2][j] != rowsum)
            return false;
    }
    if (arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2] != rowsum)
        return false;

    if (arr[0][2] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][0] != rowsum)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void create() {
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++) {
                cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to run your code in your debugger and step line by line through your code. You can start with a conditional breakpoint. You should call `srand(time(NULL));` only once in your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a debugger for such problems.

I think you code crashes because of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < cols; j++) {
```

It looks like you mean `j < cols` here :)

Answer (score 1):

Check line 76. When I compile and run the code, line 76 is where the exception is thrown.

This line specifically

```
arr[i][j] = n;
```

It seems your insertnumber() function is the culprit.